# How to get all the tags inside tbody?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tBody like this i want to rtrive data all the tags from this tbody

```
   <tbody id="tbBaby Doll Vol Six">
           <tr>
             <td align="center">001</td>
              <td width="3%">10017</td>
              <td width="7%">Baby Doll Vol Six</td>
              <td>INR&nbsp;1500.00</td>
              <td align="center">S_36</td> 
              <td align="center">0</td>
              <td align="center">
               <input type="hidden" name="rate" id="rate1" value="1500.0"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="dynamic(this.checked,'txtQty1','rate1');" name="all" value="1024-S_36-1500.0">
                    <input type="text" name="txtQty" id="txtQty1" onkeypress="checkNum('Err_txtQty1');" onblur="checkZiro('txtQty1'); subS('txtQty1','rate1');" style="width:20%;" disabled="disabled"><div id="Err_txtQty1"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td align="center">002</td>
              <td width="3%">08</td>
              <td width="7%">Baby Doll Vol Six</td>
              <td>INR&nbsp;250.00</td>
              <td align="center">S_36</td> 
              <td align="center">5</td>
              <td align="center">
               <input type="hidden" name="rate" id="rate2" value="250.0"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="dynamic(this.checked,'txtQty2','rate2');" name="all" value="1001-S_36-250.0">
                    <input type="text" name="txtQty" id="txtQty2" onkeypress="checkNum('Err_txtQty2');" onblur="checkZiro('txtQty2'); subS('txtQty2','rate2');" style="width:20%;" disabled="disabled"><div id="Err_txtQty2"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
             </td>
            </tr>           
         </tbody>`
```

From above tbody i want to retrive all the tags and its value in javascript. how can i do this?

Comment: what do you mean all tags? do you want to read all inputs?

Comment: means you want  `<td align="center">001</td>` and so on ?

Comment: Post a *very simple `<table>`*, then show *exactly* what output you want, and in what format (String, Object, Array, JSON...). Don't leave it to us to guess what you want. Also: show what you've tried already, and where - and how - it went wrong.

Comment: no i just want input type hidden, checkbox and text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('tbody *');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    if(element.tagName === 'INPUT'){
        console.log(element.value);
    }else{
        console.log(element.textContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final solution (you can replace `td.text()` with somthing else):

```
var data = [];
$('tbody tr').forEach(function(tr) {
    var data[data.length] = [];
    $(tr).find('td').forEach(function(td) {
        data[data.length].push(td.text())
    });
})
console.log(data);
```